# Don't cascade deletes to secondary table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I am having a hibernate entity mapped to a table, say ABC where I have declared a `@SecondaryTable`, say XYZ.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ABC")
@SecondaryTables({ @SecondaryTable(name = "XYZ", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "xyz", referencedColumnName = "abc")) })
public class AbcClass {
    //...some atributes

    @Column(table = "XYZ", name = "xyz")
    private String abcDesc;

    //...getter setters
}
```

Now, if I delete a row from table ABC, I do not want it to cascade to XYZ.
How can I do this?

Comment: Change your mapping and use a OneToOne. SecondaryTable means that a single entity is mapped to two tables. You have to independent entities.

Comment: Hi @JB Nizet, I changed the mapping to one to one but after that when I see the console there are multiple queries executing, i.e. if the child table is having 10 records for a record in primary table, 10+1 queries are executing. But when I user SecondaryTable, only one query is executed and I get all the results.
Could be please explain this behavior.
Thanks

Comment: If the child table has 10 records for a single parent table, the association is a OneToMany, not a OneToOne. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: @JB Nizet, sorry I confused a completely different scenario while writing this. 
Actually the mapping is one to one, when any select statement is executed, first the select is for primary table then select statements for all the records in foreign key table.
So if parent table and child table has 10 records with one to one mapping, total statements executed are 11.

Comment: That's because the query doesn't fetch the associated table. Learn JPQL and use something like `select foo from Foo foo left join fetch foo.bar where ...`

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, I am using Spring data JPA and with current one to one mapping, I mentioned my query in jpa repository as suggested by you. Now it is only a single query executing.
@Query(value="select ABC from TableA ABC join fetch ABC.XYZ join fetch ABC.DEF")
Thank you very much